# Dask Distributed Diagnostic Webpage not working

Tags: python, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, dask

I've gotten `dask` up and running on my cluster, but I can't seem to access the diagnostic webpage. The landing page is visible, see below:

[image]

But all the links just hang and never load the page.

The scheduler started fine with this output:

```
[hoffmand@h05u06 ~]$ dask-scheduler --scheduler-file dask-scheduler.json
distributed.scheduler - INFO - -----------------------------------------------
distributed.scheduler - INFO -   Scheduler at:   tcp://10.36.105.16:8786
distributed.scheduler - INFO -       bokeh at:              0.0.0.0:8788
distributed.scheduler - INFO -        http at:              0.0.0.0:9786
distributed.bokeh.application - INFO - Web UI: http://127.0.0.1:8787/status/
distributed.scheduler - INFO - -----------------------------------------------
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Register tcp://10.36.107.15:37780
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Starting worker compute stream, tcp://10.36.107.15:37780
```

Comment: I can confirm that this happens quite frequently

Comment: I guess you don't have a solution ... ?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately not. I had the impression that after a fresh installation of anaconda, it is more likely that all interfaces work, and after a while, they don't show up any more.

Comment: Can you please post the exact versions of dask, distributed, bokeh and tornado?

Comment: Sorry did a fresh installation and everything seems to be working fine now.

Comment: I've started having issues again, here's the versions:
     dask,                      0.15.0,                   py35_0;
     distributed,               1.17.1,                   py35_0;
     bokeh,                     0.12.4,                   py35_0;
     sockjs-tornado,            1.0.3,                    py35_0;
     tornado,                   4.5.1,                    py35_0;

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced the same issue, and apparently, with `bokeh` <= 0.12.5 and `tornado` = 4.5 (see https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/1027)

So either:

- Downgrade your `tornado` to 4.4.3
- Upgrade `bokeh` to 0.12.7 (or at least 0.12.6 [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508308/bokehwebinterface-not-working-for-dask-distributed))

I just upgraded to `bokeh` 0.12.7 and it works like a charm.