# BokehWebInterface not working for Dask Distributed

Tags: distributed, dask

I have updated my Dask from version 0.14.3 to 0.15.0, and distributed from 1.16.3 to 1.17.0. BokehWebInterface has been removed from this version. The homepage can be loaded http://localhost:8787, but I can't access tasks, status, workers(It tries to reload until all task are finished and then gives can't reach error). Everything used to work on the earlier version.

```
loop = IOLoop.current()
t = Thread(target=loop.start)
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
workers = []
services = {('http', HTTP_PORT): HTTPScheduler, ('bokeh', BOKEH_INTERNAL_PORT): BokehScheduler}
port = 8786
scheduler = Scheduler(loop=loop, services=services)
workers = []
bokeh_web = None
try:
    scheduler.start(port)
    # removed after updating the dask and ditributed
    bokeh_web = BokehWebInterface(http_port=HTTP_PORT, bokeh_port=BOKEH_PORT)
    # start workers
    for resource in resources:
         workers.append(Worker(scheduler.ip, port, **opts).start(0))
finally:
    for worker in workers:
        worker.stop()
    scheduler.stop()
    bokeh_web.close()
```

Comment: There is a known issue with Bokeh version <= 0.12.5 and Tornado=4.5.  Can you check if this is the case for you?  This is fixed in the next version of Bokeh, which will be released tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, my current version of Bokeh is 0.12.5, Tornado is 4.5.1. Thanks for the input, I'll update my Bokeh tomorrow.

Comment: You can also downgrade tornado to 4.4 if you want something earlier

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed with 0.12.6 version of Bokeh. Thanks, @MRocklin for the inputs.

Comment: I believe Bokeh 0.12.6 is only on the conda "bokeh" channel at this moment, but presumably will percolate to conda-forge and defaults soon enough.