# Dask Distributed Diagnostic Webpage hangs not openning links

Tags: bokeh, dask

I start my dask-scheduler and open bokeh web page. But when trying to access the links it just hangs on loading. I tried re-installing everything (dask and bokeh) but the issue remains. Is this a known issue? I am not using conda to install it. It is similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483820/dask-distributed-diagnostic-webpage-not-working) but their solution didn't work on me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tornado version 4.5 and Bokeh versions <= 0.12.5 have a known incompatibility.  Try updating bokeh to 0.12.6 or downgrading Tornado to 4.4